# Specify fields of related model in Django GeoJSON serializer field

Tags: python, django, geojson, django-serializer

I am trying to plot the latlong points in the map using **geojson serializer**. For this functionality, I have two models named `Activity` and `ClusterA`.

**Activity** is a model that stores data for some activity defined in a project. This activity contains a `PointField` field called `location`. 
This is my `Activity` model:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    target_number = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    target_unit = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    beneficiary_level = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    weight = models.FloatField(default=0)
    location = PointField(geography=True, srid=4326, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def latitude(self):
        if self.location:
            return self.location.y

    @property
    def longitude(self):
        if self.location:
            return self.location.x
```

Similarly, an activity can belong to a cluster. This data is stored in the model **ClusterA**(Cluster Activity). **ClusterA** refers to the activities that are specific for a cluster.

**Cluster model**

```
class Cluster(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ward = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**ClusterA model**

```
class ClusterA(models.Model):
    activity = models.ForeignKey('Activity', related_name='clustera')
    target_number = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    target_unit = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, default='')
    time_interval = models.ForeignKey(ProjectTimeInterval, related_name='cainterval', null=True, blank=True)
    target_completed = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    interval_updated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    target_updated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    location = PointField(geography=True, srid=4326, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def latitude(self):
        if self.location:
            return self.location.y

    @property
    def longitude(self):
        if self.location:
            return self.location.x

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
        if not self.id:
            if not self.activity.beneficiary_level:
                self.target_unit = self.activity.target_unit
            self.time_interval = self.activity.time_interval
        return super(ClusterA, self).save()
```

Now I am using a function that returns the geojson data for the cluster activities as:

```
def get_map_data(request):
    ca = ClusterA.objects.all()
    data = serialize(
        'geojson',
        ca,
        geometry_field='location',
        fields = ('activity', 'location', )
    )
    print(data)
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

The output I get is:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "crs": {"type": "name", "properties": {"name": "EPSG:4326"}}, "features": [{"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [85.336775, 27.542718]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {"activity": 27}}, {"geometry": null, "type": "Feature", "properties": {"activity": 19}}, {"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [85.336776, 27.735227]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {"activity": 26}}]}
```

The **activity** field gives the id for the **activity**. But I require the **activity name** so that **I can display the activity name in the pop up of marker plotted in the map**.

This is how I am trying to display the name of activity in popup of the marker:

```
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
   layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
}
```

The popup displays other data if I pass the fields of local model to it.

**I have tried using:**

```
fields = ('activity__name', 'location', )
```

In the **get_map_data** function, but it does not display the field in the print output as:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "EPSG:4326"
    }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          85.336775,
          27.542718
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {

      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": null,
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {

      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          85.336776,
          27.735227
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {

      }
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, there is no field specified in the `properties` of above output.

**The help I need is to be able to fetch the name field of the activity model rather than the id.**

I am using `Django 1.8`.

**Edit:**
The output of print(ca.**dict**) after adding `select_related`

```
{'activity_id': 44, 
'target_unit': u'Check', 
'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x7f57e19c8150>, 
'target_completed': 0, 
'cag_id': 35, 
'target_updated': False, 
'_activity_cache': <Activity: Test>, 
'location': <Point object at 0x7f57e19391c0>, 
'time_interval_id': 84, 
'target_number': 12, 
'interval_updated': False, 
'id': 72}
```

**Error Traceback for custom serializer**

```
ERROR 2019-06-12 14:40:15,638 base 27641 140154705491712 Internal Server Error: /core/get-map-data/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sanip/.virtualenvs/mes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/sanip/naxa/mes-core/onadata/apps/core/views.py", line 366, in get_map_data
    data = serializers.serialize(ca, geometry_field='location', fields=('activity__name', 'location',))
  File "/home/sanip/.virtualenvs/mes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 69, in serialize
    self.end_object(obj)
  File "/home/sanip/naxa/mes-core/onadata/apps/core/serializers.py", line 170, in end_object
    super(CustomSerializer, self).end_object(obj)
  File "/home/sanip/.virtualenvs/mes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 61, in end_object
    cls=DjangoJSONEncoder, **self.json_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 189, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 434, in _iterencode
    for chunk in _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 408, in _iterencode_dict
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 408, in _iterencode_dict
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 442, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "/home/sanip/.virtualenvs/mes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 115, in default
    return super(DjangoJSONEncoder, self).default(o)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <Point object at 0x7f783f0c92e0> is not JSON serializable
Internal Server Error: /core/get-map-data/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sanip/.virtualenvs/mes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/sanip/naxa/mes-core/onadata/apps/core/views.py", line 366, in get_map_data
    data = serializers.serialize(ca, geometry_field='location', fields=('activity__name', 'location',))
  File "/home/sanip/.virtualenvs/mes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 69, in serialize
    self.end_object(obj)
  File "/home/sanip/naxa/mes-core/onadata/apps/core/serializers.py", line 170, in end_object
    super(CustomSerializer, self).end_object(obj)
  File "/home/sanip/.virtualenvs/mes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 61, in end_object
    cls=DjangoJSONEncoder, **self.json_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 189, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 434, in _iterencode
    for chunk in _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 408, in _iterencode_dict
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 408, in _iterencode_dict
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 442, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "/home/sanip/.virtualenvs/mes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 115, in default
    return super(DjangoJSONEncoder, self).default(o)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <Point object at 0x7f783f0c92e0> is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Can you show us the result of `print(dict(ca))` in the `get_map_data` function?  I think you need to use a join here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, django serializer does not provide ForeignKey values. So you can override the [geojson](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/serializers/geojson.py) serializer fields. For example:

```
from django.contrib.gis.serializers.geojson import Serializer 

class CustomSerializer(Serializer):

    def end_object(self, obj):
        for field in self.selected_fields:
            if field == 'pk':
                continue
            elif field in self._current.keys():
                continue
            else:
                try:
                    if '__' in field:
                        fields = field.split('__')
                        value = obj
                        for f in fields:
                            value = getattr(value, f)
                        if value != obj:
                            self._current[field] = value

                except AttributeError:
                    pass
        super(CustomSerializer, self).end_object(obj)
```

Usage:

```
serializers = CustomSerializer()
ca = ClusterA.objects.all()
data = serializers.serialize(ca, geometry_field='location', fields=('activity__name', 'location', ))
```

Comment: This gives me the error that **TypeError: <Point object at 0x7f3ade019b50> is not JSON serializable**. Maybe the custom serializer requires some modifications?

Comment: I have included it in the question.

Comment: The updated answer did work. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need to do is `JOIN` the activity table using `.select_related()` property:

```
def get_map_data(request):
    ca = ClusterA.objects.all().select_related()
    data = serialize(
        'geojson',
        ca,
        geometry_field='location',
        fields = ('activity', 'location', )
    )
```

Let me know what happens when you try this.

If this doesn't work, try:

```
def get_map_data(request):
    ca = ClusterA.objects.all().select_related('activity__name')
    data = serialize(
        'geojson',
        ca,
        geometry_field='location',
        fields = ('activity', 'location', )
    )
```

Comment: OP may have to do a `select_related('activity__name')`

Comment: Just did that and it's still giving me the activity id instead of the name.