# How to include related fields when serializing to geojson in django

Tags: django, django-queryset, geojson, geodjango

I have two models. The first contains point data. The second is a ForeignKey back to the point model.
How do I include fields from the second model when seralizing the first model?

```
class Site(models.Model):
    ptgeom = models.PointField(srid=2953, blank=True, null=True)
    ...

class File(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='File', max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

In my view I build a queryset of the visible points and attempt to pass it back to the map:

```
def file_points(request):

    ...
    q_set = Dmsesite.objects.filter(ptgeom__contained=geom)
    points_as_geojson = serialize('geojson', q_set, geometry_field='ptgeom')    
    return JsonResponse(json.loads(points_as_geojson))
```

From this, I get a json of all the point records in q_set. I want this to include the File records as well.

I have searched but am really lost.
I have attempted .select_related(), but from the Site side the File model is not actually a related field.

I attempted to follow this question:
[Specify fields of related model in Django GeoJSON serializer field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56106245/specify-fields-of-related-model-in-django-geojson-serializer-field)
and create the CustomSerializer, but I still didn't get any File records.

Another possibility may be to somehow build a new queryset on the opposite side (File side) based on the current queryset (Site), but I'm not sure how I would go about this as I think it would result in multiple querysets (one for each site)?

This seems like it should be something that is encountered frequently, but I am totally stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.